# Is it possible to get the exact value of the integration?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following code in Mathematica.

```
α = 3;
f[s_] := Exp[-A*s^(2/α)];
F = Assuming[{A > 0, t > 0, {t, A} ∈ Reals}, 
   Integrate[f[s]*Exp[s*t] /. s -> I*y, {y, 0, Infinity}]/Pi];
Z = FullSimplify[
   ComplexExpand@Re[F], {t > 0, A > 0, {t, A} ∈ Reals}];
S = Assuming[{A > 0, A ∈ Reals}, 
   Integrate[t*Exp[-t*x]*Z, {t, 0, Infinity}]];
Q = Assuming[{A > 0, A ∈ Reals}, Integrate[S, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

I get the output in terms of AiryAi function. Is it possible to get the exact value of this integration. For example, when $\alpha=4$, I get exact value. But for $\alpha=3$, Mathematica does not solve it and give me a value as in the case of $\alpha=4$. It keep all the integral limits.

Here, $Q$ is some probability. But I do not get it like 0.3 or 0.4 etc.
Let say

```
A = Pi*λ*P^(2/α)*Gamma[1 + 2/α]*Gamma[1 - 2/α];
```

where P=2,$\lambda=20$.

Comment: Have you used a virgin kernel and ClearAll["Global`*"] before each recalculation? N[Q] results in 1.000000000000

Comment: your question is confusing because in mathematica "exact" means specifically "not numerical". I gather from your comment you actually will be happy to have a numerical result.  Maybe edit the question to clarify what you are seeking.

Answer (score 3):

MMA can't solve this integral symbolicall,only numericall.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]


\[Alpha] = 3;
f[s_] := Exp[-A*s^(2/\[Alpha])];
F = Assuming[{A > 0, t > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals},Integrate[f[s]*Exp[s*t] /. s -> I*y, {y, 0, Infinity}]/Pi];
Z = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand@Re[F], {t > 0, A > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals}]

P = 2;
\[Lambda] = 20;
A = Pi*\[Lambda]*P^(2/\[Alpha])*Gamma[1 + 2/\[Alpha]]*Gamma[1 - 2/\[Alpha]];

Q = NIntegrate[t*Exp[-t*x]*Z, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
Method -> {"DoubleExponential", "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}, MaxRecursion -> 200]
```

$$Q=1$$

**Edited:**

I give  You an example for $\alpha =4$, because MMA can solve it symbolically.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Remove["Global`*"]


\[Alpha] = 4;
f[s_] := Exp[-A*s^(2/\[Alpha])];
F = Assuming[{A > 0, t > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals}, 
Integrate[f[s]*Exp[s*t] /. s -> I*y, {y, 0, Infinity}]/Pi];
Z = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand@Re[F], {t > 0, A > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals}]
```

$$\frac{A e^{-\frac{A^2}{4 t}}}{2 \sqrt{\pi } t^{3/2}}$$

```
S = Assuming[{A > 0, x >= 0},Integrate[t*Exp[-t*x]*Z, {t, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]]
```

$$\frac{A e^{-A \sqrt{x}}}{2 \sqrt{x}}$$

```
Q = Assuming[A > 0, Integrate[S, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

$$1-e^{-\sqrt{10} A}$$

```
 P = 2;
 \[Lambda] = 20;
 A = Pi*\[Lambda]*P^(2/\[Alpha])*Gamma[1 + 2/\[Alpha]]*Gamma[1 - 2/\[Alpha]] // N
 (* Q is a probability*)
 Q // N
```

for $P=2$ and $\lambda=20$ is $A\approx 139.577$ then: 
$$Q=1$$

The same is probably when $\alpha =3$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not that good at calculas.But where is the numerical solution? You mean I cannot get values like 0.3 or 0.4. Its a definite integral! Then what is the point of solving this integral if I cannot get the result. And what do you mean by (*Output Q = 1. *)?

Comment: Yours numerical solution is 1.